# What the 404 error when im trying download file with POST to my api?

Tags: api, go, download

Here api to go which should load the file when posting a request of the form

```
curl -X POST -d "url = http: //site.com/file.txt" http: // localhost: 8000 / submit
```

But 404 gets out, what's the reason?
Or how to download files via POST in API?

```
func downloadFile(url string) Task {
    var task Task
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while downloading")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    filename := strings.Split(url, "/")[len(strings.Split(url, "/"))-1]
    fmt.Println(filename)
    out, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while downloading")
    }
    defer out.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("Error while downloading")
}

func submit(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Header("Content-Description", "File Transfer")
    c.Header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
    url := c.Param("url")
    fmt.Println("url " + url)
    task := downloadFile(url)
    hashFile(task.ID)
    c.JSON(200, task.ID)
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/submit/:url", submit)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP status 404 means the server couldn't find the requested URL. This appears to make perfect sense given your curl command.  You appear to be requesting the URL `http://localhost:8000/submit`, but your application only has a single route:

```
router.POST("/submit/:url", submit)
```

This route requires a second URL segment after `/submit`, such as `/submit/foo`.